# Expression syntax in function main (Turbo-C)

Tags: c, dos, turbo-c

I'm using a DOS virtual machine to bypass a segfault, yet Turbo-C doesn't want to compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
       FILE *fp = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");
       if(fp == NULL) {
               fprintf(stderr, "NaF");
               return -1;
       }
       char /*1*/ *ch = NULL;
       while(ch /*2*/ < (char *) 209* /*3*/1024) {
                fprintf(fp, "& - %p, * - %c\n", ch, *ch/*4*/);
                ch++;
       }
       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
}
```

Error list:

1. Expression syntax in function main
2. Undefined symbol 'ch' in function main
3. Illegal use of pointer in function main
4. Invalid indirection in function main

I assume this must be some kind of ancient C, because I'm positive this code would compile on a modern compiler. I am aware it would produce a segfault, hence why I'm writing in a DOS environment.

Comment: Perhaps using a compiler from the 21st century might help

Comment: @EdHeal No, I explicitly stated that I'm using Turbo-C to avoid a segfault. Any modern OS would kill the program on the first iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: Don't use TurboC. Never. Don't do it. Really.

Comment: How many times do I have to repeat that I used Turbo C only to avoid a segfault and have no intention to keep using it unless I want raw access to memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) and 2) Turbo-C used the C90 version of the standard. It did not allow variable declarations in the middle of a `{ }` body, but only at the top. Therefore `char* ch` has to be moved:

```
int main (void)
{
  char* ch = NULL
  ...
```

3) You try to multiply a pointer `(char *) 209`. This simply isn't allowed in C and will not compile on modern compilers either.

And finally, pointer arithmetic `ch++` used on a pointer which doesn't point at an allocated object isn't well-defined by any version of C. It *probably* worked in Turbo C, but no guarantees.

I think this program was supposed to grab a memory dump of RAM and store it to a text file. MS DOS allowed direct access of memory. However, the code was already questionable even back in 1989.

Using `char` for accessing raw memory is a bad idea, since it is a type with implementation-defined signedness. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly it. I can confirm it still works in Turbo C :) 
I was just curious to know what the RAM contains.